# How to do url encode of json in ruby

Tags: php, ruby, json, urlencode

I want to encode a recipients json using ruby method,
   Below is the sample code,

```
recipients = 
{
"1JzSZFs2DQke2B3S4pBxaNaMzzVZaG4Cqh": 100000000,
"12Cf6nCcRtKERh9cQm3Z29c9MWvQuFSxvT": 1500000000,
"1dice6YgEVBf88erBFra9BHf6ZMoyvG88": 200000000
}
```

**Example url formation in php,**

```
<?

$guid="GUID_HERE";
$firstpassword="PASSWORD_HERE";
$secondpassword="PASSWORD_HERE";
$amounta = "10000000";
$amountb = "400000";
$addressa = "1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq";
$addressb = "1ExD2je6UNxL5oSu6iPUhn9Ta7UrN8bjBy";
$recipients = urlencode('{
              "'.$addressa.'": '.$amounta.',
              "'.$addressb.'": '.$amountb.'
           }');

$json_url = "http://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/sendmany?password=$firstpassword&second_password=$secondpassword&recipients=$recipients";
```

how to do this urlencode using ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URI.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html)

```
require 'uri'

enc_uri = URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
p enc_uri
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'

enc_uri = URI.encode_base64("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")

p enc_uri
```